# How to compare 2 lists containing json values in C# for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How to compare 2 lists in c#?
1st list data

```
DBvalues = [{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d98298f9110f5f13812f3c1"), "PartName" : null, "MAP" : null, "MPN" : null, "IsActive" : true, "Gtin" : "ab085347019069" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("5d98298f9110f5f13812f3c0"), "PartName" : null, "MAP" : null, "MPN" : null, "IsActive" : true, "Gtin" : "085347014064" }]
```

2nd list data

```
actualExcelvalues = [{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d98298f9110f5f13812f3c0"), "PartName" : null, "MAP" : null, "MPN" : null, "IsActive" : true, "Gtin" : "085347014064" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("5d98298f9110f5f13812f3c1"), "PartName" : null, "MAP" : null, "MPN" : null, "IsActive" : true, "Gtin" : "ab085347019069" }]
```

irrespective of their order/index.

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare: number and name of nodes? or node values?

Comment: To compare whether the object id(other fields also) in the 1st list is same as in the 2nd list..Same for other key and values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the strings then AreEqual works.

If you mean the objects then my technique for testing is to serialise both to indented json and compare that. Crude, but does the job.

---

In my current setup I have a  static `AreEqual<T>(T expected, T actual)` which serialises both and then compares line by line to show better output when comparing fails.